# Multi-select Checkbox Preventing Page From Saving

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectcheckboxes

I have a form that contains two multi-select checkboxes in order to select certain days of the week. The first multi-select checkbox works completely fine and I can save the values. However, when I select boxes for the second set of checkboxes it prevents the page from being saved.

I have created the following test controller and page to mimic the issue-- with this example, neither of the checklists will let me save. The logs on my console do not show any errors, just a new log for the page after it refreshes when I press save. Why doesn't it forward the page when I save?

Controller:

```
public class TestVFPage_Controller {

public String[] weekdays1 {get; set;}
public String[] weekdays2 {get; set;}

   public PageReference save() {
        PageReference saved = new PageReference('/apex/TestVFSavePage');
        saved.getParameters().put('Weekdays1',String.valueOf(weekdays1));
        saved.getParameters().put('Weekdays2',String.valueOf(weekdays2));
        saved.setRedirect(true);
        return saved;
   }


   public List<SelectOption> getDayOptions() {
        List<SelectOption> weekdays = new List<SelectOption>();
        weekdays.add(new selectOption('Monday','Monday'));
        weekdays.add(new selectOption('Tuesday','Tuesday'));
        weekdays.add(new selectOption('Wednesday','Wednesday'));
        weekdays.add(new selectOption('Thursday','Thursday'));
        weekdays.add(new selectOption('Friday','Friday'));
        weekdays.add(new selectOption('Saturday','Saturday'));
        weekdays.add(new selectOption('Sunday','Sunday'));
        return weekdays;
    }



}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page tabStyle="HigiConnector_HomePage__tab" controller="TestVFPage_Controller">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Checkbox 1" for="dayInvite" />
                        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!weekdays1}" id="dayInvite" layout="pageDirection">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!dayOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Checkbox 2" for="refreshInvite" />
                        <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!weekdays2}" id="refreshInvite" layout="pageDirection">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!dayOptions}"></apex:selectOptions>
                        </apex:selectCheckboxes>
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not instantiating the Lists to hold the selected values.

Add this to your controller:

```
public TestVFPage_Controller(){
    weekdays1 = New String[]{};
    weekdays2 = New String[]{};
}
```

This will instantiate the lists. If you had a page messages component on your page you would have saw the error:

[image]

Which would have alerted you to the error.

An alternate way of doing this would be:

```
public String[] weekdays1 = New String[]{};
public String[] weekdays2 = new String[]{};

public String[] getweekdays1(){
    return weekdays1;
}

public void setweekdays1(String[] weekdays1){
    this.weekdays1 = weekdays1;
}

public String[] getweekdays2(){
    return weekdays2;
}

public void setweekdays2(String[] weekdays1){
    this.weekdays2 = weekdays1;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't they also be `List<SelectOption>`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - I do not believe so as it stores the value not the select option object itself. Tested and working

Comment: Oh...I see it now. D'oh!

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you! I will start adding the page message component to my pages. It has been so frustrating not seeing any errors. And I now see what is happening.  In my original code I have this `public String[] inviteWeekdays {get; set;}` and it works fine which has been really misleading. I probably instantiated the list somewhere in my code and have been overlooking it. Thank you again!